# Moving around a number grid

Tags: python

been trying to  make a snakes and ladders, thought it would be easy but im having issues with moving around the board. i can obviously do the first move, i cant however do the second one as i cant figure out how to move onto my next list element and retian the numbers left of my roll. heres my code so far:

```
import random
pOnePos =[0,0]
pTwoPos =[0,0]

board = [['1','2','3','4','5','6','7'],
         ['8','9','10','11','12','13','14'],
         ['15','16','17','18','19','20','21'],
         ['22','23','24','25','26','27','28'],
         ['29','30','31','32','33','34','35'],
         ['36','37','38','39','40','41','42'],
         ['43','44','45','46','47','48','49']]

newpos = pOnePos

rnd = random.randrange(1,7)
newpos[1] += rnd
board[pOnePos[0]][pOnePos[1]]="P1"

for row in board:
    print("\t".join(row))
```

Can anyone shed some light so i can carry on, i dont want anyone to DO the solution but explain how i can jump elements and retain a number, of course im also going to keep a total with this so i know im on position 33 if i rolled the dice to get to this number. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  can store the sum of the rolls in addicional variable

```
sum_of_rolls+=rnd
```

and calculate the row as

```
 row=sum_of_rolls//size_of_row
```

where size_of_row is 7  in your case, and then calculate the column(position in the row) as

```
column=sum_of_rolls-row*size_of_row
```

then access the board as

```
board[row][column]
```

Comment: wow, never thought of seeing it like this, i can see why it works but my head cant get around the 2d array, thanks a lot this has given me enough!

Comment: in not sure how this is traversing the list at all, i get the floor division bit but the column element im not sure